# Can you use pandas groupby to group rows, determined by summing a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to group rows in a dataframe by values of one column. The example given below would be if i were grouping the values of 'NumberOfTrades' by values of 150, so the top 2 rows are grouped and the bottom 3 rows are grouped. The next step, which I understand will require some further steps is to compute Open from the first of each group, Close from the last of each group, High from the largest of each group and Low from the smallest of each group.

```
Time     Open   High  Low  Close  NumberOfTrades
17:35     101.1   102  100  101         75
18:42     101     105  101  103         75
18:56     103     108  102  107         50
19:45     107     105  101  103         50
20:01     103     104  101  102         50
```

```
Time    Open    High  Low  Close  NumberOfTrades
17:35    101.1   105  100  103         150
18:56    103     108  101  102         150
```

Using `df = df.groupby('Time')['NumberOfTrades'].sum(freq=1000).to_frame()` just creates a new dataframe with column Time and NumberOfTrades, and I assume by grouping each 1000 rows. Whilst I actually want to sum the values of NumberOfTrades to 1000. Without also losing the other columns.

and using `df = df.groupby(['Time', 'Open', 'High' 'Low', 'Close'])['NumberOfTrades'].sum(freq=1000).to_frame()` creates a dataframe of shape 1xlen(column of NumberOfTrades) whilst I desire a 6xN

I have also tried using `df = df.groupby('Time')['NumberOfTrades'].sum(value=1000).to_frame()` trying to sum values up to 1000 for 'NumberOfTrades', but the shape remains constant as I adjust value from 10 -> 10000

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['grp'] = (df['NumberOfTrades'].cumsum() % 150).diff().fillna(0).lt(0)[::-1].cumsum()

dd = {'Time':'first',
      'Open':'first',
      'High':'max',
      'Low':'min',
      'Close':'last',
      'NumberOfTrades':'sum'}

df.groupby('grp', sort=False)[['Time','Open','High','Low','Close','NumberOfTrades']]\
  .agg(dd).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    Time   Open  High  Low  Close  NumberOfTrades
0  17:35  101.1   105  100    103             150
1  18:56  103.0   108  101    102             150
```

Comment: Thank you so far, as this somewhat makes sense to me. However, substituting the 150 for 10000, my NumberOfTrades column in my actual dataframe contains numbers like : 2,4,1,5,7

Comment: Ah i see, that the values of grp are descending from N, N-1, N-2. However they are not yet collapsed into one row, i.e. the top values are 66010, 66010, 66010, 66010, 66009, 66009, 66009, 66009, 66009, 66009, etc

Comment: I am getting this error ```FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```. So the aggregation of the grouping may not be working properly

Comment: As far as your future warning.... check your column names match the keys in the dictionary.  No duplivate column names.

Comment: You can just check for `.eq(0)` instead of `.diff().fillna(0).lt(0)`. That would be faster. `df['grp'] = (df['NumberOfTrades'].cumsum() % 150).eq(0)[::-1].cumsum()`

Comment: I ended up using NamedAgg and instead of first and last which can't be used by NamedAgg, I used aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0]) for date and open and aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[-1]) for close

Comment: Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `.eq(0)` instead of `.diff().fillna(0).lt(0)` in @Scott Boston's solution.

```
dd = {'Time':'first',
      'Open':'first',
      'High':'max',
      'Low':'min',
      'Close':'last',
      'NumberOfTrades':'sum'}

df['grp'] = (df['NumberOfTrades'].cumsum() % 150).eq(0)[::-1].cumsum()
df.groupby(by='grp', sort=False)[['Time','Open','High','Low','Close','NumberOfTrades']].agg(dd).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: agg doesn't have use of first or last I believe. Unless this is just in NamedAgg.

Comment: I ended up using NamedAgg and instead of first and last which can't be used by NamedAgg, I used aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[0]) for date and open and aggfunc=lambda x: x.iloc[-1]) for close

Comment: Didn't 'first' and 'last' give you the same result?